# How do i print text into a .txt file using python

Tags: python

I want to make a program that prints multiple text into a notepad by using a python script and I found out a way to do it but then when I try to make a loop where `n = 0` and then `n = n + 1` and it loops 5 times, and then I want it to write that text into a `.txt` file.

When I check the the `.txt` file it only says `5` and not `1 2 3 4 5` which is what I wanted it to say, I have also tried moving parts of the code for example the `file.close()`, I tried moving it outside of the loop but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
n = 0
for x in range(5):
    n = n + 1
    n1 = str(n)
    print(n1)
    file = open('database.txt','w')
    file.write(n1)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Move the file open to before the loop. What you are doing is reopening the file for each loop iteration and it is getting overwritten. You can also open the file to append in each iteration but that's slow and inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you should search a bit before creating an answer. You are opening and writing to file each loop. If you want to keep the loop, use 'a+' instead of 'w'

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python write text to file", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use 'a' instead of 'w':

```
n = 0
for x in range(5):
    n = n + 1
    n1 = str(n)
    print(n1)
    file = open('database.txt','a')
    file.write(n1)
file.close()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what `"a"` does and what `"w"` does. It would be even better with a reference to the official documentation.